# UILabel appearance doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, uiappearance

It seems that `[UILabel appearance]` doesn't work anymore with latest iOS SDK.

Let's take this as an example:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UILabel appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 80, 200, 100)]];
}
```

This code won't display the label with the red background.

If, on the other hand use this code:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIImageView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 80, 200, 100)]];
}
```

then the red area is visible.

Even if I change the property, i.e. change the font instead, or the text color (and display some text of course), no changes are visible.

On most S.O. questions regarding UILabel and appearance, although some people did have some problems, in general it seems to work, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try putting `[[UILabel appearance] blah blah]` after `[self.view addSubview: blah blah]`.

Comment: @CosmosMan That won't work. Settings made on `appearance` only work on views created after the setting is made.

Comment: @matt For educational purposes mostly. Just to know my limits. Of course I know the existence of the backgroundColor property and how to use it. Just consider the scenario that I want a global theme on my application -- isn't that what UIAppearance is for?

Answer (score 0):

The comments from @matt made me find the error. (Unfortunately he has retracted his answer so I can't give him the credits he deserves, if @matt you are listening, please give another answer in order to get the credits).

The reason why it was that, it is because it seems to be a Bug in iOS 12.
Under (beta) iOS 13 the behavior is as expected.